# Why won't my objects print?

Tags: c#, object, accessor

New to the site as well as c#. This is my first time using c# and I can't get my objects to print properly. (example Million, Max 55. Cardenas, Jose, 22). I am pretty sure the error is in my accessors but I can't seem to get it right.

```
  using System.IO;
  using System;

  class PersonApp
   {
  static void Main()
   {
    Random random = new Random();
    Person p1 = new Person();
    Person p2 = new Person();

    p1.Fname = "Max";
    p1.Lname = "Million";
    p1.Id = random.Next(1,100);

    p2.Fname = "Jose";
    p2.Lname = "Cardenas";
    p2.Id = random.Next(1,100);

    Console.WriteLine(p1,p2);
  }
}



   using System.IO;
   using System;

   public class Person
   {
     private string Fname;
     private string Lname;
     private int Id;

  public Person(){
    Fname = string.empty;
    Lname = string.empty;
    Id = 0;
  }

   public string Fname
    {
    get
    {
        return Fname;
    }

    set
    {
        Fname = value;
    }
   }

    public string Lname
   {
    get
    {
        return Lname;
    }

    set
    {
        Lname = value;
    }
   }

   public int Id
  {
    get
    {
        return Id;
    }

    set
    {
        Id = value;
    }
   }



   }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Do you understand what it means?

Comment: "The type `Person' already contains a definition for `
Fname'" I am getting this error for every private variable. Is it because I declared them as empty and 0?

Comment: you are using accessors  wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access property of the method to get the values printed

Wrong code :

```
   Console.WriteLine(p1,p2); // You are trying to print Objects and this is wrong. !!
```

Correction : Use accessory's get to print the output.

```
   Console.WriteLine(p1.Fname); // Print first name "Max"
```

Likewise

```
   Console.WriteLine(p1.Lname); // print Last name
   Console.WriteLine(p1.Id);  // Print ID
```

Also your class need to be corrected

```
  using System.IO;
  using System;

  public class Person{

        private string fname;
        private string lname;
        private int id;

        public string Fname
        {
            get
            {
                return fname;
            }

            set
            {
                fname = value;
            }
        }

        public string Lname
        {
            get
            {
                return lname;
            }

            set
            {
                lname = value;
            }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }

            set
            {
                id = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can use it like

```
        Person a = new Person();
        a.Fname = "k";
        a.Lname = "Do";
        a.Id = 1024;

        Console.WriteLine(a.Fname+" "+a.Lname+" "+a.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues in your code.

First, you can't pass multiple values to `Console.WriteLine` like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(p1, p2);
```

Do one at a time:

```
Console.WriteLine(p1);
Console.WriteLine(p2);
```

Second, you can't name your private backing field and the public property used to get/set it the same. You can name them whatever you want... typically the private variable starts with a lower case or an underscore, but that's up to you.

Once you fix those, you'll still get unusual output, which is actually the full namespace of your class. That's the result of `ToString()` being implicitly called when you pass `p1` to `Console.WriteLine`.

Override the `ToString()` method in your class:

```
public class Person
{
    private string Fname;
    private string Lname;
    private int Id;

    private override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1} {2}", Lname, Fname, Id);
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect C# to know the format you want the object output in. You have to concatenate the strings yourself to produce the output.

The neatest way to do this is expose a readonly property on `Person` that formats it how you want, something like this:

```
public string DisplayName {
    get {
        return Lname + ", " + Fname + " " + Id;
    }
}
```